# Cleanest design pattern for displaying form data and validation errors?

Tags: python, design-patterns, forms

In real-life applications, if I use a form framework, I inevitably end up fighting it at some point.

I'm interested in best practice patterns for building forms in a website.  Reference to implementations in any language would be a bonus (I usually work in Python).  I'm particularly interested in the problem of creating / displaying the forms to the end user.

Here's how I see the subject. Most parts of the form workflow can be handled with relatively lightweight components that I can pull out of frameworks like [formencode](http://formencode.org/) and [formish](http://ish.io/projects/show/formish).  By "most parts" I mean **decoding** submitted form data into a sensible data structure (e.g. repeated fields in the form should become lists in Python); **marshalling** the values into the types that we want (e.g. an "age" field should become an integer); and **validating** the values (e.g. "age must not be blank").

The bit I end up fighting is making and displaying the forms themselves.  Many frameworks (e.g. [FormAlchemy](http://code.google.com/p/formalchemy/)) tightly couple their schemas, validation and models to some kind of form widget generation scheme, which I don't like.

The tasks involved in making a form are:

- Making dynamic widgets (e.g. a select list with values from a database)
- Looping over repeating fieldsets (e.g. a list of name, age pairs that each represent a person)
- Embedding existing values in the form fields (from a data structure)
- Displaying validation errors next to form fields or at the top of the page

The options I see for doing this are:

- **generate**, based on widgets that are defined in the schema (e.g. [Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/))
- **post-process** forms, by applying a data structure containing errors and values to an HTML template (e.g. [htmlfill](http://formencode.org/htmlfill.html))
- accept that for all but the simplest cases, you may as well start from the beginning by encoding the logic (loops, error display, etc) **manually** in each of your form templates

Are there any other patterns for handling the problem?  What are the pros and cons of each?

*The frameworks (Python) I've looked at / had pointed out so far are: [flatland](http://discorporate.us/projects/flatland/docs/tip/), [formencode](http://formencode.org/), [FormAlchemy](http://code.google.com/p/formalchemy/), [formish](http://ish.io/projects/show/formish), [WTForms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/), [Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) forms, [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/), [deform](http://docs.repoze.org/deform/), [FormConvert](http://jimmyg.org/work/code/formconvert/) and [web.py](http://webpy.org/cookbook/forms)*

**Update:** I've not really got very far with answering the question about best practise for building forms, but I've made the decision with my current project to go for deform / colander, which is a sane way of handling serialisation etc, but more importantly is well-documented and well-tested.  I am going to avoid form generation at all for all but the simplest forms.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question the way you did. My requirements are nearly identical to yours. Based on your update, you abandoned form generation. But regarding populating forms with values, were you able to find a good solution? Are you using htmlfill for this purpose for example? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try `django`. It has `forms` module, that provides many useful mechanisms for web forms.

Comment: As mentioned, I already know Django -- I'm interested in design patterns (especially to the form-filling part of the problem), rather than big frameworks.  Also, the Django forms implementation is very tightly coupled to the entire framework.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [web.py](http://webpy.org/)'s Form class which you may find interesting. There are examples in its [cookbook](http://webpy.org/cookbook/).

Comment: I hadn't looked at web.py, thanks -- but it appears to be yet another form generation framework.  What would make it different / better than, say, formencode?

Answer (score 1):

You might check out [web2py](http://www.web2py.com), which provides several mechanisms for [generating and processing forms](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/07) (see also form-related [Javascript and Ajax functionality](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/10)). Its form objects (and other HTML helper objects) are server-side representations of the HTML DOM and can be manipulated prior to serialization into HTML (see [ref1](http://www.web2py.com/AlterEgo/default/show/217), [ref2](http://www.web2pyslices.com/main/slices/take_slice/43), [ref3](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/05#HTML-Helpers), [ref4](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/05#Server-side-DOM-and-Parsing)). If you have further questions about it, ask on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).

Answer (score 1):

A panel featuring several form library authors was presented at PyCon 2010, which might be relevant to your question:

http://www.pycon.tv/video/184/

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful discussion

Comment: This link seems to be broken.

Comment: Thank you, @Matthew, the old link was indeed broken; I found the video somewhere else and have updated the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have recently used [flatland](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/flatland) to handle a complex form and found it to be very flexible. There's no widgets library, but it has a powerful HTML generator/filter, and as [pointed out](http://dag-flatland.readthedocs.org/en/latest/patterns/widgets/) in the documentation, it's quite simple to write your own widgets. Don't let the "0.0.2" version fool you, the library is quite mature and stable.

Answer (score 0):

have you seen Bruno's [django-floppyforms](https://github.com/brutasse/django-floppyforms)? It doesn't answer your question but it's worth being aware of it being done.